How to solve lemon-graph installation Error?
i clone the git repository from https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/lemon-graph.git,  i followed installation steps,

cd lemon-graph

mkdir build && cd build

cmake .. // Upto this there was no error

make // i got the error as per image
i am a newbie to linux, help me to install lemon-graph for OpenROAD installation.
The Error :
krishna_rk@krishnark:~/lemon-graph/build$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target lemon
[  4%] Building CXX object lemon/CMakeFiles/lemon.dir/soplex.cc.o
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:31:18: error: allocation of incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   31 |     soplex = new soplex::SoPlex;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:36:5: warning: deleting pointer to incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex' is incompatible with C++2c and may cause undefined behavior [-Wdelete-incomplete]
   36 |     delete soplex;
      |     ^      ~~~~~~
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:43:18: error: allocation of incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   43 |     soplex = new soplex::SoPlex;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:44:7: error: static_cast from 'soplex::SoPlex *' to 'soplex::SPxLP *' (aka 'SPxLPBase<double> *'), which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed
   44 |     (*static_cast<soplex::SPxLP*>(soplex)) = *(lp.soplex);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: 'SoPlex' is incomplete
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:76:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   76 |     soplex->addCol(c);
      |           ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:80:18: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   80 |     return soplex->nCols() - 1;
      |                  ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:87:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   87 |     soplex->addRow(r);
      |           ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:91:18: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
   91 |     return soplex->nRows() - 1;
      |                  ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:100:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  100 |     soplex->addRow(r);
      |           ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:104:18: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  104 |     return soplex->nRows() - 1;
      |                  ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:109:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  109 |     soplex->removeCol(i);
      |           ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:117:11: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  117 |     soplex->removeRow(i);
      |           ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:179:31: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  179 |     for (int j = 0; j < soplex->nCols(); ++j) {
      |                               ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:180:13: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  180 |       soplex->changeElement(i, j, 0.0);
      |             ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:183:13: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  183 |       soplex->changeElement(i, it->first, it->second);
      |             ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:188:40: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  188 |     const soplex::SVector& vec = soplex->rowVector(i);
      |                                        ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:196:31: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  196 |     for (int i = 0; i < soplex->nRows(); ++i) {
      |                               ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:197:13: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  197 |       soplex->changeElement(i, j, 0.0);
      |             ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:200:13: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  200 |       soplex->changeElement(it->first, j, it->second);
      |             ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.cc:205:40: error: member access into incomplete type 'soplex::SoPlex'
  205 |     const soplex::SVector& vec = soplex->colVector(i);
      |                                        ^
/home/krishna_rk/lemon-graph/lemon/soplex.h:32:9: note: forward declaration of 'soplex::SoPlex'
   32 |   class SoPlex;
      |         ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [lemon/CMakeFiles/lemon.dir/build.make:216: lemon/CMakeFiles/lemon.dir/soplex.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:337: lemon/CMakeFiles/lemon.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
krishna_rk@krishnark:~/lemon-graph/build$



-Help me to solve this error.

Mon, 07 Jul 2014 16:41:54 +0200 - very old software likely expects particular compiler extensions. Report the issue on GitHub.

Okay, Thank you
